# prove $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\frac{y_n}{x_n}}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Suppose that ${x_n}$ and ${y_n}$ are real sequences such that $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
If ${y_n}$ is bounded and $x_n \neq0$, then prove $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\frac{y_n}{x_n}}=0$.

Here is my proof, Can anyone tell me is there anything wrong?

$\bullet$ Choose $M_1>0$ such that $|y_n|\leq M_1$

$\bullet$ Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ implies $x_n>\frac{M_1}{\epsilon}$. then $n\geq N$ implies
$$|\frac{y_n}{x_n}|=\frac{|y_n|}{x_n}<\epsilon$$.

Comment: Nothing wrong. It is neat.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you

Comment: Which part(s) seem doubtful to you?

Comment: Depending on the course you're taking and if you want to hand in your solution for homework points or something like that, you might want to add some details (e.g. why does such $N\in\mathbb N$ exists such that $x_N>\frac{M_1}{\epsilon}$?), but the core of your answer is correct.

Comment: @Hirshy I got it thank you

Comment: @SenZen my textbook proof is somewhat different that is why I checked this

Comment: When you have absolute values around something tall, such as a fraction, you can use `\left` and `\right` to automatically resize them: `\left| \frac{x}{y} \right|` yields $$\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|$$This can be done with a lot of other delimiters too, including `(), [], \langle\rangle, \{\}`. Note that each `\left` must have a matching `\right`, but they don't need to have the same type of bracket (use a dot `.` for an invisible bracket, i.e. if you only want a bracket on one side).

Comment: @noname and what? Now that some people online have told you it's right, you'll just believe them?

Comment: @Arthur Thank you very much for that

Comment: @SenZen absolutely not actually I want to make sure I feel it correct but if there is anything wrong that I can't see that is why I ask it